# Reset dropdown lists using javascript

Tags: javascript, textbox, drop-down-menu, onfocus

I have the following scenario - a few dropdwon lists and a textbox.

I'd like to 'reset' these drop downs to their original value when a user clicks on the textbox:

Javascript:

```
function ResetDropDowns() 
{
    var ddlSuppliers = document.getElementById('<%=ddlSuppliers.ClientID%>');
    var ddlResponse = document.getElementById('<%=ddlResponse.ClientID%>');
    var ddlImportStatus = document.getElementById('<%=ddlImportStatus.ClientID%>');

    ddlSuppliers.selectedIndex = -1;
    ddlResponse.selectedIndex = -1;
    ddlImportStatus.selectedIndex = -1;  
}
```

Code behind:

```
tbxAutoCompleteSupplier.Attributes.Add("onFocus", "return ResetDropDowns();");  

protected void ddlSuppliers_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ddlSuppliers.Items.Insert(0, 
    new ListItem("--Please Select Supplier--", "0"));
}
```

However, this does not seem to do the business.

Any ideas?

Comment: out of curiosity what eventually was the culprit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you changing the index to `-1` while your default item is at index `0`?

```
ddlSuppliers.selectedIndex = 0;
ddlResponse.selectedIndex = 0;
ddlImportStatus.selectedIndex = 0;
```

Should do the trick.

**Update**

Can you verify if the dropdowns are set? To debug the ResetDropDowns() method just type the keyword `debugger` at the beginning. This will break the compiler so you can step through the code.

Example:

```
function ResetDropDowns() 
{
    debugger; //compiler will break here
    var ddlSuppliers = document.getElementById('<%=ddlSuppliers.ClientID%>');
}
```

Comment: Hello Peter - I've changed that to 0 but still no joy - something odd is afoot.

Comment: @Ricardo - have you tried manually calling ResetDropDowns() and see if it works?

Answer (score 0):

this is actually because of conflict between this javascript and our CMS' jquery - all sorted now!

Resolution:

I wrapped the controls in a div (called wrapper) and then applied the .uniform to the controls within said div.

```
function pageLoad(sender, args) {
        if (args.get_isPartialLoad()) {
            $("#wrapper select, #wrapper span, #wrapper input").uniform();
        }
    }
```

That ensures the css is maintained.

Thanks for the suggestions though.